# implements IEnumerable to add a IWord object

Tags: winforms, word-cloud

I downloaded a [cloud control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/224231/Word-Cloud-Tag-Cloud-Generator-Control-for-NET-Win) in C# 
it uses **IEnumerable** to countOccurence,Sort and filter 
i wanted to make a method which help me to add a **IWord(string text,int occurence)**

other methods are

```
public static IEnumerable<IWord> CountOccurences(this IEnumerable<string> terms)
    {
        return 
            terms.GroupBy(
                term => term,
                (term, equivalentTerms) => new Word(term, equivalentTerms.Count()), 
                StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                .Cast<IWord>();
    }
public static IEnumerable<string> Filter(this IEnumerable<string> terms, IBlacklist blacklist)
    {
        return
            terms.Where(
                term => !blacklist.Countains(term));



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IEnumerable<IWord> AddOwnItems(this IEnumerable<string> terms)
    {
        IEnumerable<IWord> obj = new List<IWord>()
        {
          new Word("Development", 12), new Word("Extractor", 24), new Word("Anyother", 18)
        ,new Word("wao", 12),new Word("yours", 18),new Word("how does", 28),new Word("coudnt", 20),new Word("adkj", 22),
        new Word("own", 12),new Word("items", 10),new Word("terms ", 14),new Word("whats", 12),new Word("uupp", 16),
        new Word("Zar E Ahmer", 36),new Word("Cool", 26),new Word("Yhoo", 18),new Word("I am", 14),new Word("never", 16),
        new Word("thirty May", 12),new Word("string", 10),new Word("nothing", 14),new Word("much", 12),new Word("Disney", 16)
        };
        return obj;

    }
```

i use this code than my problem is solved